# How to repeat / freeze a row (which is other than the top row) on every page in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet which contains some data on the first few rows and after that, the actual table starts. I want to freeze the row from where the table starts.

From my little research, it seems that Google sheets can only freeze the rows starting from the top.

Is it possible to freeze a separate row which is not at the top?

Any workarounds are welcome too.

Attached screenshot of my sheet for reference. I want to freeze the 8th and 9th row only.

[image: sheet screenshot]

Comment: any particular reason why you want to do this? (answer could depend on it)

Comment: Because I want to print the sheet. So if it exceeds one page then the table headers should be repeated on every page.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print the sheet. So if it exceeds one page then the table headers should be repeated on every page

in that case freeze it till 10th and before print just hide 1-7

[image: 0]

Comment: But I want the first few rows to be printed as well in the first page.

Comment: the only option is to reprint the 1st-page-only afterwards with unhidden rows

Comment: Sorry I cant do that as it should be an automated process.
I have created an issue on Google Issue tracker for feature request of improving the freeze functionality.
Here is the link
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129220853